# Why do these two logarithmic binning methods give different results? (in R)

Tags: r, histogram, binning

## Problem

I am working on a problem involving logarithmic binning. I have a dataset consisting of individuals that have a size value and a production value. I am using an algorithm to logarithmically bin the individuals by size so that I can look at the relationship between size class and total production in that size class.

Once I have the logarithmic bin edges, I can calculate total production in each bin by assigning each individual to a bin and adding up their production. However, I would also like to be able to generate fitted values from a density function I've fit to the data. For that, I need to multiply the fitted number of individuals in each bin by the median production value for the bin. However, this gives very different values, as I demonstrate with this toy example below. I would appreciate help in figuring out why the two methods give systematically different results. Apologies in advance for the lengthy amount of code in the question!

## Code

#### Toy dataset

```
sample_dat <- structure(list(size = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 
1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.9, 1.9, 2, 2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 
2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 3, 3, 
3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 
4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 4.6, 4.6, 4.7, 4.9, 5.5, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 
5.8, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 6.6, 7, 7.1, 7.6, 8.1, 8.6, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.5, 
9.7, 9.8, 11.1, 11.3, 12.4, 12.9, 13.3, 13.9, 16.4, 20, 44.9306174730365, 
50.5329545454011, 60.8468023871241), production = c(0.0229639600198833, 
0.0467035124475317, 0.0228829663828679, 0.0555196717601559, 0.0266894404145689, 
0.086888835240009, 0.0659616825069015, 0.0528198938272874, 0.0791033601880049, 
0.0310676179497369, 0.139084437055257, 0.03715266983121, 0.0843085721125607, 
0.101829995351614, 0.049776002419228, 0.146447979949806, 0.0445484378591824, 
0.0445484378591824, 0.0716160101868882, 0.0987792612347305, 0.0373911276341316, 
0.130803332178573, 0.0382738504622522, 0.107030398878202, 0.118273850293712, 
0.158023145888448, 0.231656714629965, 0.137189043026162, 0.114005268808464, 
0.211851836061739, 0.114005268808464, 0.253857978793635, 0.137628173123624, 
0.2877794380997, 0.37047470407231, 0.35638407237573, 0.0642614920068561, 
0.073774642285394, 0.371238570209438, 0.4624617433484, 0.234909017496227, 
0.15265351358196, 0.0956308262651823, 0.185308346520668, 0.1236536324256, 
0.167723289396746, 0.53067323837342, 0.100638257059151, 1.1251433567678, 
0.106414300864168, 0.842203718787293, 0.345836190556719, 0.230678421052428, 
0.230678421052428, 0.141574990490483, 1.26691858574501, 0.710420177868528, 
0.167391397052897, 0.121865018293573, 0.221143473413854, 0.99202805556954, 
0.202066318668007, 0.267854574929469, 1.19990195991582, 0.726280945949195, 
0.167081670819599, 0.227807214644717, 1.41051789654916, 1.79100818796434, 
0.34694985158708, 1.14825266968833, 0.331044278710521, 0.9428043085197, 
1.40653319950317, 2.16454342116466, 2.63928691348633, 1.0722018958848, 
1.23753553767681, 0.467853010778889, 1.18141464747918, 7.35607617342681, 
1.93643494853573, 1.31144037161, 1.78703051509879, 0.710731000134784, 
2.71806232092321, 3.77455440344602, 5.27907480680308, 0.604121631720616, 
16.5694752334547, 6.41404420370017, 19.4803316268777, 1.29612475962156, 
9.43165028809657, 51.1621457918011, 25.9656807881876, 4.79490681824243, 
509.885620477642, 39.4808739249175, 390.769485440482)), .Names = c("size", 
"production"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Function for logarithmic binning

```
logbin <- function(x, y = NULL, n) {
  logx <- log10(x)                                           # log transform x value (biomass)
  bin_edges <- seq(min(logx), max(logx), length.out = n + 1) # get edges of bins
  logxbin <- rep(NA, length(logx))                           # create data structure to assign trees to bins
  b <- bin_edges                                             # add a little to the biggest bin temporarily
  b[length(b)] <- b[length(b)] + 1                           # (so that the biggest single tree is put in a bin)
  for (i in 1:length(logx)) {
    logxbin[i] <- sum(logx[i] >= b)                          # assign each tree to a bin
  }
  bin_midpoints <- numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    bin_midpoints[i] <- mean(10^(bin_edges[i:(i+1)]))        # backtransform bin edges to linear, and get midpoints
  }
  bin_widths <- diff(10^bin_edges)                           # get linear width of each bin
  bin_factor <- factor(logxbin, levels=1:n)                  # convert bin to factor (required to deal with zeroes if present)
  bin_counts <- table(bin_factor)                            # find number of trees in each bin
  if (!is.null(y)) {
    rawy <- tapply(y, bin_factor, sum)                       # sum y value (production) in each bin
    rawy[is.na(rawy)] <- 0                                   # add zeroes back in if present
    bin_values <- as.numeric(rawy/bin_widths)                # divide production by width for each bin 
  }
  else {
    bin_values <- as.numeric(bin_counts/bin_widths)          # 1-dimensional case.
  }

  return(data.frame(bin_midpoint = bin_midpoints,            # return result!
                    bin_value = bin_values,                  # also add bin min and max for bar plot purposes
                    bin_count = as.numeric(bin_counts),
                    bin_min = 10^bin_edges[1:n],
                    bin_max = 10^bin_edges[2:(n+1)]))

}
```

#### Function to get median production in a bin

```
production_median_fn <- function(dat, bins) {
  bin_medians <- numeric(nrow(bins))
  for (i in 1:nrow(bins)) {
    min_i <- bins$bin_min[i]
    max_i <- ifelse(i < nrow(bins), bins$bin_max[i], bins$bin_max[i] + 1) # Make sure the largest individual is in a bin
    bin_medians[i] <- median(dat$production[dat$size >= min_i & dat$size < max_i])
  }
  bin_medians[is.na(bin_medians)] <- 0
  bin_medians
}
```

#### Method 1 to bin total production per size class

```
# Bin total production
total_production_bin <- logbin(x = sample_dat$size, y = sample_dat$production, n = 10)

# Confirm that method 1 gives correct results.

sum(sample_dat$production)
```

That returns 1132.837

```
# Back calculate by multiplying by bin width again.
# This is the same value as the actual total production.
sum(with(total_production_bin, bin_value * (bin_max - bin_min)))
```

That also returns 1132.837

#### Method 2 to get total production by size class

This uses the median production value per bin.

```
production_medians <- production_median_fn(sample_dat, total_production_bin)

total_production_product <- density_bin$bin_count * production_medians / with(total_production_bin, bin_max - bin_min)

sum(total_production_product * with(total_production_bin, bin_max - bin_min))
```

That returns 1325.229.

```
data.frame(method_1 = total_production_bin$bin_value, method_2 = total_production_product)

#         method_1   method_2
#    1   1.5704257  1.3962571
#    2   4.1885892  3.4354781
#    3   6.1262342  3.6163614
#    4   4.1399519  1.6427196
#    5   8.2205314  5.6792102
#    6   9.6960547  6.0556345
#    7  17.7876413 16.1413397
#    8   0.5319476  0.5319476
#    9   0.0000000  0.0000000
#    10 46.7423323 58.2856444
```

The two methods give very different results for most of the bins. I cannot explain why this would be the case. The toy example only has a few bins but the same problem occurs with thousands of data points and many bins. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that you are working with *densities*.  It's not appropriate just to sum the values when the bin widths vary: You must multiply the values by the bin widths.

Comment: I did multiply the values by the bin widths as in `sum(total_production_product * with(total_production_bin, bin_max - bin_min))` @whuber

Comment: I hope you will forgive me for overlooking that within your 100 or so lines of code.  Perhaps you could provide, in words, a synopsis of what you're doing so that this doesn't just turn into a code review.

Comment: @whuber I apologize for having such long code. What I am trying to do is to estimate total production per size class by multiplying the number of individuals per size class (generated by logarithmic binning) by the average production per individual in that size class. However that method is giving results that differ systematically from what I expect.